# Swagger UI integration with Camel ...not able to access index.html on port

Tags: apache, spring-boot, apache-camel, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Camel to integrate Swagger. I downloaded dist folder renamed to swagger and updated index.html but I'm not able to access ui it through my application port: http://localhost:${port}/${contextPath}/swagger/index.html

but if I type http://localhost:${port}/api-doc, I get the swagger json dump.

I can access index.html if go to the file and open it manually with browser. How do i access index.html using my application port?

http://localhost:${port}/${contextPath}/swagger/index.html

Comment: Are you using a web.xml file? If so, can you please post it?

Comment: no web.xml I'm using camel rest route

Comment: I'm using Camel to integrate Swagger. I downloaded dist folder renamed to swagger and updated index.html but I'm not able to access ui it through my application port: http://localhost:${
port}/${
contextPath}/swagger/index.html

but if I type http://localhost:${
port}/api-doc, I get the swagger json dump.

I can access index.html if go to the file and open it manually with browser. How do i access index.html using my application port?

http://localhost:${
port}/${
contextPath}/swagger/index.html

Comment: Please post your route.

Comment: restConfiguration().component("{{rest.camel.component}}")
                .port("{{rest.port}}")
                .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
                .enableCORS(true)
                .apiProperty("cors", "true")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

Answer (score 3):

You need to expose an endpoint that would return your index.html file. Try adding the following to your RouteBuilder:

```
rest("/swagger")
  .produces("text/html")
  .get("/index.html")
  .responseMessage().code(200).message("Swagger UI").endResponseMessage()
  .to("direct://get/swagger/ui/path");

from("direct://get/swagger/ui/path")
  .routeId("SwaggerUI")
  .setBody().simple("resource:classpath:/swagger/index.html");
```

The first route defines a restful endpoint */swagger/index.html* that accepts a GET request and returns text/html.

The second route uses Camel's Simple component to read the actual *index.html* into the Exchange Message Body.

So if you go to *localhost:${port}/${contextPath}/swagger/index.html*, it should load the *index.html* file correctly.

Note that inside *indext.html* you need to substitute the URL that would return the JSON dump of your API so that the Swagger UI can render it.

Comment: with these changes when i go to swagger/index.html page it displays "" thats all. How do I get this route pick swagger ui that is placed inside /resources/swagger/index.html?

Comment: I guess its just creating a dummy route with no link to swagger ui. how do I link this route to swagger ui code? This is how I wrote the router:

rest("/swagger/index.html")
                .get()
                .to("direct:get/swagger/index.html");
from("direct://get/swagger/index.html")
                .routeId("SwaggerUI")
                .enrich("file://http://localhost:{{rest.port}}/swagger/index.html")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class);

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find resource: classpath:index.html in classpath for URI: classpath:index.html

Comment: No. it just loads and dumps the content index.html file . I wanted swagger UI to run with that link. If I browser index.html through IDE directly it works perfectly but it runs on totally random port and i wanted it to run on application port 8080.

Comment: Ok I edited the answer one more time and tested it locally. There were a few issues: 1) it should've been `resource:classpath:/swagger/index.html` instead of just `resource:classpath:index.html`. 2) the rest endpoint should specify that it returns HTML so that the browser can process it as such, instead of processing it as normal text (i.e. text dump). This is done by adding the `.produces("text/html")`. Try it now.

Comment: Now it shows text box with no url ( should be http://localhost:8080/api-docs) and no css and images. I guess we need to include everything under swagger folder not just index.html

Comment: Developer console says failed to load sources for js, img and css files

Comment: Yes, you need to copy everything into your `/webapp` directory.

Comment: I'm using Spring boot and all the resources are read from src/main/resources folder and this is where I have all my swagger UI /dist/ files (css, js and htmls) but because we only mentioned html in our our router, other files are not being loaded in the browser

Comment: Because we use .produces("text/html") , other files are not being loaded. i see in my browser complaining "unable to load resources 404 for all.css, .js files.

Comment: No, this is not because of `.prodcuces("text/html")`. The browser correctly processes the page as HTML but then it tries to get the other resources that are linked in the HTML doc from the server but fails since the server doesn't recognize the request

Comment: You need to add one more route to serve static resources (css/js/img) requested by index.html:
from("servlet:///?matchOnUriPrefix=true").process(e -> {
            String path = e.getIn(HttpMessage.class).getRequest().getRequestURI();
           e.getIn().setBody(new ClassPathResource(path));
        });

Answer (score 0):

I am using Camel Jetty as the REST component. For jetty you just need add an additional ResourceHandler to handle SwaggerUI resource. Below using Spring xml language to configure REST:

```
<restConfiguration component="jetty" host="{{rest_hostname}}" port="{{rest_listen_port}}"
                       bindingMode="off" apiContextPath="api-docs" apiContextListing="true"
                       enableCORS="true">
        <!--ResourceHandler to handle Swagger UI contents on the jetty-->
        <endpointProperty key="handlers" value="swaggerUIHandler"/>
......
......
</restConfiguration>
```

I use swaggerUI in a jar provided by webjars. Configure handler bean:

```
<bean id="swaggerUIHandler" class="com.yifanwu.examples.camel.JettyResourceHandlerFactory" factory-method="buildResourceHandler">
        <!--your resource path is just "swagger" assuming it is on the classpath-->
        <constructor-arg name="resourcePath" value="META-INF/resources/webjars"/>
</bean>
```

Bean factory:

```
public class JettyResourceHandlerFactory {
    public static ResourceHandler buildResourceHandler(String resourcePath) throws Exception {
        ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();
        rh.setResourceBase(JettyResourceHandlerFactory.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResource(resourcePath)
                .toURI().toString());
        return rh;
    }
}
```

Full example Here: [github](https://github.com/yifanwu8/examples/tree/master/camel-swagger)

Answer (score -1):

An easier solution would be to add a *web.xml* file, move your resources to your */webapp* directory, adding the following filter in *web.xml*

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>RestSwaggerCorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.camel.swagger.servlet.RestSwaggerCorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>RestSwaggerCorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/api-docs/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

See the Camel Swagger documentation for details: http://camel.apache.org/swagger-java.html

Comment: I'm using  Swagger in rest-dsl from same documentation. Should be same